# javascript bind validators

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Ive got some validators in my UpdatePanel. If OnServerZValidate returns false corresponging message is displayed atthe wrong field but all javascript I used to bind some options on click to some classes isnt working.

this is the script, it works if the page is loaded for the first time:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
InitiateData();
});

function InitiateData() {
$('.shade').bind('click', function() {
alert("test");
}
```

if there is a postback from validators alert doesnt work :)

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(InitiateData);